# Why does the `for` method not work for the belongTo relationship?

Tags: eloquent-relationship, laravel-10, laravel-testing, laravel-factory

I want to test the memberOfTeam relationship from the User model using factories. According to the [Laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-factories#belongs-to-relationships), I should use for, but it doesn't work and it creates 3 users with team_id as null for me. (team_id is nullable by default.)

How can I solve this problem using factories?

laravel:10
php:8.1

in User Model:

```
public function memberOfTeam(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(
        Team::class ,
        'id' ,
        self::TEAM_ID
    );
}
```

in Team model:

```
public function members(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, User::TEAM_ID);
}
```

**Each team needs a user_id to be created**, which is the manager of that team.

in tests/Feature/Model/UserTest:

```
    $count = 3;
    $team = Team::factory()
        ->for($this->makeUser(), TeamRelation::MANAGER)
        ->create();
    $user = $this->makeUser()
        ->count($count)
        ->for($team, UserRelation::MEMBER_OF_TEAM)
        ->create();
```